# Angular js returning error Unknown provider:

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I created a factory dtoResource.js to work with my data as per different form.

I am trying to inject this factory in autoQuoteCtrl in autoQuoteCtrl.js file.

But its giving error

```
angular.js:13424 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- dtoResource
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/unpr?p0=%24resourceProvider%20%3C-%20%24resource%20%3C-NaNtoResource
    at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular.js:68:12
    at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular.js:4418:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular.js:4571:39)
    at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular.js:4423:45
    at getService (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular.js:4571:39)
    at injectionArgs (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular.js:4595:58)
    at Object.invoke (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular.js:4617:18)
    at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular.js:4464:37)
    at Object.invoke (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular.js:4625:19)
    at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular.js:4424:37
```

What I am missing here.

Comment: It won't solve your issue but you might want to look at https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1 . It might get you your issue solved sooner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the `angular-resource` script. It's in a different module.

Here's a cdn reference you can use if you want.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
```

And make sure you add it as a dependency to your module:

```
var app = angular.module("autoQuote",["ui.router", "ngResource"]);
```